# Crossing data from a netcdf file with data in a csv file

Tags: r

I have data which is stored in a netcdf file and was downloaded from Copernicus. I am trying to extract the Sea Surface Temperature from the file and save it as a raster stack in ascii format. This seems to work fine. There is a problem when trying to cross the data in the netcdf file with my data stored in a table in csv format. I have put an example of what the csv looks like. I want to be able to have an additional column with the SST.

| Year | Month | Day | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 6 | 1 | 36.94695 | -8.788889 |
| 2010 | 6 | 1 | 36.94750 | -8.804167 |

I have attached my script below. The problem occurs with the for loops and I get this error:

`Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero`

```
#### script to cross SST dataset with absence data ####

# load packages
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(readr)

temp <- raster::stack("cmems_mod_ibi_phy_my_0.083deg-3D_P1M-m_1694536161344.nc copy")
writeRaster(temp,"/Users/lukeainsworth/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UniversityofPlymouth/OneDrive - University of Plymouth/Ocean Science and Marine Conservation/Dissertation/Dissertation_R/Temperature/",bylayer=T,format="ascii",overwrite=T)

absence_dataset <- read.csv("absence_dataset.csv")
abs_dataset_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data=absence_dataset,coords = absence_dataset[,c("Latitude","Longitude")], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

# loads 138 .asc files
SST <- list.files("/Users/lukeainsworth/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-UniversityofPlymouth/OneDrive - University of Plymouth/Ocean Science and Marine Conservation/Dissertation/Dissertation_R/Temperature",full.names = F, pattern = ".asc")

numeric_part <- as.numeric(gsub("_|\\.asc","",SST))
SST <- SST[order(numeric_part)]

Year <- formatC(2020:2021, width = 4, format = "d")
Month <- formatC(1:12, width = 1, format = "d")
Day <- formatC(1:31,width=1,format="d")

for(Y in Year){
  for(M in Month){
    for(D in Day){
      
      pts_sub <- subset(absence_dataset,Year==Y & Month==M & Day==D)
      
      if(nrow(pts_sub)==0)next
      r_sub <- SST[grep(Y,SST)]
      r_sub <- r_sub[grep(paste0(Y,M,D),r_sub)]
      
      r_sub <- raster(r_sub)
      r_sub <- projectRaster(r_sub,crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+type=crs")
      
      rasValue <- extract(r_sub,pts_sub[,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
      pts_sub$sst <- rasValue
      poss <- match(absence_dataset$ID,pts_sub$ID,nomatch=0)
      absence_dataset$sst[poss!=0] <- pts_sub$sst[poss]
      
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone is able to help that would be great. I have been trying for ages and cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Is that the entire error message you get? There’s no traceback or mention of what function throws the error?

Comment: Try `debugonce(subset)` and step through your loop 'n' at a time ls()ing values, and from `?subset` warning:  `in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.`, as it is meant for interactive, and a `for` is nearly programming. Just thoughts on provoking the error and localizing.